# How to fetch numbers only

Tags: asp.net, regex

In the table below, I just need the first number

```
tqt
 T     P/S  NAME                   TOTAL            FOP                 SEGMENTS 
 9    .3  TMACDORMAN/SAM CORBIN    USD      1177.17 CHECK                  4-5   
 10   .1  TLOJ/DANUTA ISABELLA     USD      1341.17 CHECK                  4-5   
 10   .2  TMACDORMAN/JACK HENRY    USD      1341.17 CHECK                  4-5
```

According the above strings I need only

```
9
10
10
```

Right now I am using following regex

```
(?:\d)([0-9]{0,}(?<!\.\d))
```

But it shows the numbers of column 'FOP' and 'SEGMENT'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To capture the first number on each line (with possible spaces before it) you could use:

```
(?m)^ *(\d+)
```

[`(?m)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) makes the `^` match at the beginning of lines, not just the beginning of string.

Comment: but when i bind it with datatable it will show me only first number of the column

Comment: done thanks for your i made some changes and it work thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I tried `(\d+)\s+.*` and that seemed to work for me, if all you want is the first number.

I have ignore-case and multi-line turned on.

Comment: i want only first column number not all the number your regex give me all numbers

Comment: No it doesn't - http://screencast.com/t/GDwirGWh1kD, make sure you have the correct options turned on.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\s+(?<number>[0-9]+)[^\n]+(\n)?)+
```

And then read content of the **NUMBER** group

or if you parse each row individually

```
^\s+(?<number>[0-9]+)[^\n]+(\n)?
```